# How to send over data from database to wear?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

My program requires me to send data from a database in the phone over to android wear of the same program when a `Button` is clicked. I have been trying to send it by converting the database to `JSON` and then taking those datas from the `JSON` recieved and entering them in the database with the same name (but has an extra record). Sending the `JSON` data to the watch works perfectly fine but when it comes to receiving the data on the watch, the watch never receives it. I have tried several methods to try and see if the watch receives anything but so far nothing. I haven't implemented a `DataMap` for it like some of Google's tutorial does but I am not sure how to do so. My code below shows exactly what I have done so far:

Phone - MainPhoneApp.java's onCreate method:

```
final Button updateWearDatabaseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateWearDatabaseButton);
        updateWearDatabaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseToJSON dbJSON = new DatabaseToJSON(MainPhoneApp.this);
                try {
                    JSONArray json = dbJSON.getJSON();
                    new SendToDataLayerThread(DatabaseHelper.DB_DIRECTORY, json.toString()).start();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wear Database Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Phone - DatabaseToJSON.java:

```
package com.jawad.wifihotspotfinder;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class DatabaseToJSON {
    DatabaseHelper dbhandler;

    public DatabaseToJSON(Context context) {
        dbhandler = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public JSONArray getJSON() throws JSONException {
        String myPath = DatabaseHelper.DB_DIRECTORY; // Set path to your database
        String myTable = DatabaseHelper.DB_TABLE; // Set name of your table

        SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(searchQuery, null );

        JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
            JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();
            for( int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++ ) {
                if( cursor.getColumnName(i) != null ) {
                    try {
                        if( cursor.getString(i) != null )
                        {
                            Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i));
                            rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  cursor.getString(i) );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rowObject.put( cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  "" );
                        }
                    } catch( Exception e ) {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage()  );
                    }
                }
            }
            resultSet.put(rowObject);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d("TAG_NAME", resultSet.toString());
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

Wear - DataLayerListenerService.java:

```
package com.jawad.wifihotspotfinder;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.WearableListenerService;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class DataLayerListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

    public final String TAG = "NodeListener";

    @Override
    public void onPeerConnected(Node peer) {
        super.onPeerConnected(peer);

        String id = peer.getId();
        String name = peer.getDisplayName();

        Log.d(TAG, "Connected peer name & ID: " + name + "|" + id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
        ConnectionResult connectionResult = googleApiClient.blockingConnect(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if(!connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to connect to Google API Client");
            return;
        }

        if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(DatabaseHelperWear.DB_DIRECTORY)) {
            final String message = new String(messageEvent.getData());
            Log.v("myTag", "Message path received on watch is: " + messageEvent.getPath());
            Log.v("myTag", "Message received on watch is: " + message);

            try {
                DatabaseHelperWear myDbHelper;
                myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelperWear(this);

                try {
                    myDbHelper.createDataBase();
                } catch (IOException io) {
                    throw new Error("Unable to create database");
                }

                try {
                    myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                    throw new Error("Unable to open database");
                }

                SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                try {
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(message);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
                        initialValues.put("_id", json_data.getString("_id"));
                        initialValues.put("Type", json_data.getString("Type"));
                        initialValues.put("Postcode", json_data.getString("Postcode"));
                        initialValues.put("Latitude", json_data.getString("Latitude"));
                        initialValues.put("Longitude", json_data.getString("Longitude"));

                        String where = "_id = ?";
                        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(i)};
                        db.update(DatabaseHelperWear.DB_TABLE, initialValues, where, whereArgs);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }
                myDbHelper.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add the `AndroidManifest.xml` part.

```
<service android:name=".NodeListenerService">
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're extending `WearableListenerService` you don't need to make a connection to `GoogleApiClient`; that's all done behind the scenes. So all you really need is to process the data from the message:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(DatabaseHelperWear.DB_DIRECTORY)) {
        // process data
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. This is what my phone is saying: `02-19 00:30:49.850 14609-16699/com.jawad.wifihotspotfinder V/myTag: Message: {[{"_id":"1","Type":"Work","Postcode":"N1 9NR","Latitude":"51.531","Longitude":"-0.121539"},{"_id":"2","Type":"Home","Postcode":"WC2B 6UN","Latitude":"51.5137","Longitude":"-0.118486"}]} sent to: LG Urbane FC48` but nothing is being received in the watch.

Comment: Crap! Just realised my `AndroidManifest.xml` had the wrong name for the Listener Class.